# Are there any ways of using validation property and onChanged property inside zefyrEditor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to achieve this text editing toolbar thing and came across zefyr. I used it and that was exactly what I need. However, I have validation and onChanged property that is to be used in my custom text field. So, can anyone suggest me anyways of using validation property and onChanged property inside zefyrEditor or zefyrField in flutter.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can add to your ZefyrController the next property to add the property onChange:

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   final document = _loadDocument();
   _controller = ZefyrController(document);

   //With this you can manage the text of your ZefyrEditor
   _controller.document.changes.listen((event) {
     print(_controller.document.toString());
   });
   _focusNode = FocusNode();
}
```

In this case i'm only printing the document and this will be triggered every time you type something.